# Android - Creating contacts in phone

Tags: java, android

Hi guys i need help to understand a code that i have i didnt used it yet because i don't understand it maybe you guys could help me doing that.

```
private void createContact(String name, String phone) {
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null);

    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String existName = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            if (existName.contains(name)) {
                AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder=new AlertDialog.Builder(add_cli.this);
                dialogBuilder.setMessage("Um contacto com este nome já existe.");
                dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
                dialogBuilder.show();
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, "accountname@gmail.com")
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, "com.google")
            .build());
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
            .build());
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, phone)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME)
            .build());


    try {
        cr.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Contacto criado de seguida será adicionado como um dos seus clientes.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

I understand the first part when we search if there is any contact with that name what i dont understand its the next part when we create an arraylist. There is an account type an account name with google things this was already like this when i download the code. Is it to put contact name and the email of contact and there is way to put the cellphone number but the home phone number too? if im not explaning myself currently say it my english not that good but i try to express currently.

---EDITED----

What do i have to fill in these camps and what are these camps?

```
ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE
ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME
ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID
```

Comment: Your question is hard to answer, since it's not exactly clear what you don't understand about the code snippet. Please consult with the documentation for the classes that are used, and come back if you have more specific questions.

Comment: I was looking to the documentation and i dont really understand what is there but i can be more specific i will edit the question.

Comment: If the question is already solved/answered, please let us know what you did. Thanks.

Comment: Please fill in the answer box below to say your question is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I have set this part of the code like this.

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
        .build());
```